# Как выделить строку в гридвью при сравнении даты записи и today's date

Tags: c#, asp.net

Имеется таблица. И заполняется она так данными:

```
SELECT IncomeLetters.Income_ID, IncomeLetters.Income_Number, IncomeLetters.IncomeDate, IncomeLetters.SentAuthority, IncomeLetters.SentNum, IncomeLetters.SentNumDate, IncomeLetters.ContentLetter, IncomeLetters.IncomeAnswerTo, IncomeLetters.Deadline, IncomeLetters.Comment, IncomeLetters.imagepath, Employee.Surname, Resolution.Resolution, docState.docState, DocType.DocumentType, InDocType.InDocType, Theme.Theme FROM ....
```

Необходимо выделить строку в таблице, когда выполняется следующее условие:
`Deadline = IncomeLettersDeadline` (индекс столбца "8") - я правильно подсчитал? (начал счет "0")

```
DeadLine < Today's date
```

Код C#:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var tdday = DateTime.Now;
        var deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[9].Text);
        if (tdday > deadline)
        {
            //Setting row back colour
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
}
```

В конце получаю

> ERROR: Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime из-за некорректного значения дня недели.

```
{
    var tdday = DateTime.Now;
    var deadline = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);
    if (tdday > deadline)
    {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Трассировка стека:

```
[FormatException: Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime из-за некорректного значения дня недели.]
   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +11626318
   System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value) +83
   PreviewIncomeletter.GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Somon\Desktop\NAIK-XC\PreviewIncomeletter.aspx.cs:45
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +181
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3660
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775
```

Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт!
Решение: указал `DataFormatString={0:dd MM yyyy}` и все.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Deadline" HeaderText="Муҳлати иҷро" SortExpression="Deadline" DataFormatString="{0:dd MM yyyy}" />
```

Спасибо!